# Covert into Cakephp query with subquery

Tags: cakephp, subquery

Does anybody know how transform this query:

SELECT * from `diminventory` where partnumber='350964-B22' or partnumber in (SELECT partnumber from `dimparts` where parentpartnumber='350964-b22')

in a cakephp query

Thanks

Comment: Escape your backticks with \ please. Difference is `blah` vs. \`blah\` which is written \\`blah\\`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what you're asking for as yet, but here's a brief tutorial on cakephp querying.

```
$this->ModelName->query("SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 2;");
```

You query from the model, but you use the literal tablename. You use the SQL "AS" keyword to rename the keys of the resultant array.

Sample results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tablename] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1304
                    [user_id] => 759
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tablename] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1305
                    [user_id] => 759
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

He is asking for Cakephp query not custom SQL query. In the controller:

```
$partnumber = $this->diminventory->find('all',array('conditions' => array('diminventory.partnumber' => '350964-B22')));
$this->set('partnumber',$partnumber);
```

set function passes a variable as $partnumber to the view. Then int view (which is .ctp file) you need to output the array.

```
foreach($partnumber as $partnumbers){
echo $partnumbers;
}
```

Make sure that diminventory table has 's' after the name otherwise it won't work as this is part of Cakephp's strict naming conventions.

Tutorial for find function:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find

Answer (score 0):

To do it fully Cake'ish, you need to use [CakePHP subquery](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data):

```
$dbo = $this->User->getDataSource();
$subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields' => array('`Dimpart`.`partnumber`'),
        'table' => $dbo->fullTableName($this->Dimpart),
        'alias' => 'Dimpart',
        'conditions' => array('`Dimpart`.`parentpartnumber`' => '350964-b22'),
    ),
    $this->Dimpart
);

$subQuery = ' `DiminventoryEntry`.`partnumber` IN (' . $subQuery . ') ';
$subQueryExpression = $dbo->expression($subQuery);

$conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;
$conditions['DiminventoryEntry.partnumber'] = '350964-B22';

$result = $this->DiminventoryEntry->find('all', compact('conditions'));
```

Where `Dimpart` is your model for table `dimparts`, and `DiminventoryEntry` is your model for table `diminventory` (which is not actually Cake'ish, you should've renamed your table according to [conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/903/Model-and-Database-Conventions)).